# I have a problem with geopandas installation (conda)

Tags: geopandas

When I installed geopandas, it stuck at solving environment
What should I do?

```
(base) C:\Users\ASUS ROG>conda install geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available version
```

I've tried to make python version from 3.10 to 3.8
but it stucks too

Answer (score 0):

It is very recommended to use seperate environments for seperate uses when using conda rather than installing everything in one/the "base" environment. This will lead to less risk of conflicts between packages.

Additionally, some dependencies of geopandas in the "defaults" channel are (very) outdated, so at the moment it is recommended to use the "conda-forge" channel for geopandas.

So, please try to install like this ([source](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#creating-a-new-environment)):

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas
```